# c#: System.Web.HttpResponse class not available in intellisense

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, httpresponse

So I'm writing a program in C# Visual Studio 2013. At the top of my code, among my usings, I have:

```
using System.Web;
```

But when I try to use the line:

```
 HttpResponse httpResp = (HttpResponse)response;
```

then Intellisense says there is no HttpResponse class, in spite of the fact that HttpResponse is part of the System.Web namespace according to this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse(v=vs.110).aspx

Furthermore it doesn't give me any options as to what else I could import that would make that class available. What am I doing wrong here? Is HttpResponse deprecated? If it is, is there a different way to get the status code of an http response.

Comment: Are you referencing System.Web.dll?

Comment: Does your project have a reference to _System.Web.dll_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple dll's that have the namespace System.Web, such as System.Web.Entity.  You need to Add Reference to the base System.Web dll and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Check your project references, you're probably missing Syetem.web.