# System.Web is missing HttpResponse, HttpContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
```

System.Web is referenced in the project (System.Web.dll) but it just doesn't seem to work. It gives the error: "The type or namespace name 'HttpResponse' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)". Same error for HttpContext. Please help. I have no idea what to do. I downloaded another version of system.web but that doesn't work as well. I am trying to download a file using the save as option using this method.
System.Web.dll version - 4.7.3062.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question here:

[c#: System.Web.HttpResponse class not available in intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091629/c-system-web-httpresponse-class-not-available-in-intellisense)

I would suggest removing and adding the reference again. It's possible that the location path is incorrect. It should look like this, allowing for version difference:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Web.dll